# How can I, using a WebApplication MapGet handler, send an image as an HTTP response?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, .net-core

Here's my sample command line app. I'm using Windows 10 with dot-net 6.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
var app = WebApplication.Builder();
app.MapGet("/", MyGet);
byte[] MyGet(HttpContext context)
{
   context.Response.ContentType="image/png";
   return File.ReadAllBytes("MyImage.png");
}
app.Run();
```

When I run this and browse to the server, instead of a PNG image returned, I get the bytes in JSON/Base64 form.

Using a string return type for MyGet happily sends plain text or HTML to the client. How can I send arbitrary bytes instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the image as file download:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", MyGet);
async Task MyGet(HttpContext context)
{
   context.Response.ContentType="image/png";
   context.Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=test");
   await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(File.ReadAllBytes("MyImage.png"));
   //await context.Response.SendFileAsync(new FileInfo("MyImage.png").FullName);
}
app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you. My code reading from a file was because I wanted to post as simple code as I could while still being a useful demonstration. My actual code in fact builds the byte array in memory. I don't see a "SendBuffer" alternative to SendFile, so I may need to write the bytes out to a temp file and have a process that cleans up the completed temp files.

Comment: I've found the part I was overlooking and posted a separate answer, which I've credited you for. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(someBytes);
```

(I am grateful to user *rawel* for pointing me in this direction. I had tried `Response.Body.Write` before posting my question but this didn't work, an error complaining that synchronous writes were not allowed. In my case, sending the response is the last thing my get function does, so there's no problem leaving the async operation open.)

Comment: Glad to help. You could use an async function as well.Updated my answer.

Comment: @rawel - Since you've updated your answer I'll delete mine. No point having two answers with the same content.